# Can a wicket AjaxSubmitLink behave like a ResourceLink onSubmit()?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a wicket form with multiple components and a button in the bottom to validate the user input and generate a file to download upon successful validation.

I am using an AjaxSubmitLink to display the user feedback when the onError() is called but I am puzzled on how to have the onSubmit() behave like a ResourceLink.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need the approach described at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/AJAX+update+and+file+download+in+one+blow because you cannot return bytes in the Ajax response.

Comment: Link is not available. Here is the new URL for that approach: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/AJAX+update+and+file+download+in+one+blow